# Why does my code not return anything

Tags: python, return

fairly new to programming and trying to learn Python at the moment. I have this code and I don't understand why I don't get a return value :(

```
balance = 3200
annualInterestRate = 0.2
monthlyInterestRate = (annualInterestRate/12 + 1)


def f(x):
    m = 0
    ba = balance 
    while m < 12: 
        ba = (ba - x)*monthlyInterestRate 
        m += 1 
    return ba

def bisection():
    a = 0
    b = balance
    c = (a+b)/2
    while a != b:
        if f(c) == 0:
            return c
        elif f(c) < 0:
            a = c
        else:
            b = c

        c = (a+b)/2 

    return c



bisection()
```

Comment: You have defined some functions, but never calls any of them.

Comment: what do you want to return? I haven't call any function. The `print c`?

Comment: In the bisection function, I call the f(x).. I don't really know, when I should call the bisection function though.

Yes, exactly. I need a value, so that ba is 0 after 12 loops.

Comment: You neither return things from the functions, nor ever call them. Why did you *expect* a return value?

Answer (score 1):

You have to explicitly use the `return` keyword. Probably where you currently have `print c`.

`f` needs to return `ba` after the while loop.

Comment: The other comments are right that you need to call the function. I thought this was a snippet. Try adding `print bisection()` at the end of the file.

Comment: This is basically the correct answer. We can't guess what else you did wrong, but functions which do not have a `return` keyword indeed do not return anything (or rather, they return `None`).

Answer (score 0):

You're being unclear about what function you expect to return a value, but as I cannot comment and prod yet I'll provide a possible answer.

First of all, in this code you never actually call any of the functions. I'm assuming this is done elsewhere.

As for `f(x)`, there's no `return value` because you have not made a `Return` statement. I would also refrain from using variables as Globals, it's typically bad practice. Instead, if you want to modify `MonthlyInterestRate` send it as a parameter to `f()` and return the new value.

`bisection` only returns if `f(c) == 0` but `f()` does not have a `Return` statement, so that will never happen. Past that, once it exits the loop it will only print c so no return value there either.

If you want to compare a function, it NEEDS a `Return`statement.

Comment: I edited my code, using return in both functions. I still don't really understand what's going wrong. Ultimately, I would like to get a value for c so that f(c) = 0

Comment: I would really recommend reading a programming guide to begin with. It's apparent you do not yet know a lot of basics. As an example here, you call your function bisection(). Now the function will run and do it's thing and that's that. It should return a value, however you never specify what to do with that value so you throw it away. If you want to print it you need to call `print bisection()` instead. Or you can save it to a variable with ex. `foo = bisection()` but you can't just call a function and expect it to do something you haven't told it to do.

Answer (score 0):

First you should add `return ba` to function `f` to make `f` return someting:

```
def f(x):
    m = 0
    ba = balance 
    while m < 12: 
        ba = (ba - x)*monthlyInterestRate 
        m += 1
    retrun ba
```

Then, add `bisection()` at the last of your script file to call it:

```
bisection()
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Now it's just won't run correctly and I have to manually interrupt..

Urhg, this is so frustrating

Comment: @Anna what do you mean `manually interrupt`? If error, what is the error msg?

Comment: I just let it run for about 2-3 minutes at it still wasn't done so I interrupted the run. There's no error message. I don't know how else to describe it, sorry.

Comment: @Anna there must be something wrong with your `while a != b:` loop code block. Maybe your code cannot evaluate `a == b`, so make you code always loops in this loop. Check this block carefully.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in your function `f` you don't have the return statement that you need if you want to check the equality with 0.

After add the return statement in the `f` function you have to write the body of your program because you just have two functions but you don't call them to get a result value...

I understand that your program has to use the `bisection function` writing

```
bisection()
```

Answer (score 0):

Two reasons.
One, your function f(x) does not have an explicit return statement. If a function doesn't contain an explicit return it will have an implicit one, that is "None" (None is a python object).
Second, the only place where f(x) is called is in bisection() which itself is never being called.
So, since none of your functions are ever called, your code isn't going to return anything.
Try calling bisection() after defining it

Comment: I edited the code, so that I use return in both functions and the bisection() is called at the end. However, no it won't stop running and I have to interrupt it manually

Comment: Probably something with your while loop.
Are you sure the condition is right?